# Adding click listener to custom button doesn't work in angular data tables

Tags: javascript, angular, datatables

I've a data table as shown below:

```
<div class="card-body table-responsive">
          <table
            class="table display table-striped table-hover table-bordered row-border hover responsive nowrap"
            datatable
            [dtOptions]="dtOptions"
            datatable=""
            #dataTable
            id="issueTable"
          >
            <thead class="headColor"></thead>
            <tbody style="text-align: center;"></tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```

**JS:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Renderer, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
import { routerTransition } from '../../router.animations';

import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';

import { IssueDataServiceService } from './issue-data-service.service';


import 'datatables.net';
import 'datatables.net-bs4';

window['jQuery'] = window['$'] = $;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-charts',
    templateUrl: './issues.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./issues.component.scss'],
    animations: [routerTransition()]
})
export class IssuesComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    // viewer = document.getElementById('view');

    /**
     * gets settings of data tables
     *
     * @type {DataTables.Settings}
     * @memberof IssuesComponent
     */
    constructor(public router: Router) { }

    @ViewChild(DataTableDirective)
    datatableElement: DataTableDirective;
    message = '';
    title = 'angulardatatables';

    @ViewChild('dataTable') table: { nativeElement: any; };
    dataTable: any;
    dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
    // someClickhandler(info: any): void {
    //     this.message = info.number + '-' + info.assignedto + '-' + info.company;
    //     console.log(this.message);
    // }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.dtOptions = {
            pagingType: 'full_numbers',
            pageLength: 15,
            processing: true,
            responsive: true,
            autoWidth: false,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            'ajax': {
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/incident-updated',
                type: 'GET',
                dataSrc: 'result',
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    title: 'Incident',
                    data: 'number'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Product',
                    data: 'u_product'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Status',
                    data: 'state'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Created By',
                    data: 'sys_created_by'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Group',
                    data: 'assignment_group'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Category',
                    data: 'u_category'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Updated on',
                    data: 'sys_updated_on'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Action',
                    data: null,
                    // render: function(data, type, full) {
                    //     return '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="color: #fff;" id="view" (click)="view($event)">View</a>';
                    // }
                    defaultContent: '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary viewer"> View </button>'
                }
            ]
        };
        let table = this.dataTable;
        table = $(this.table.nativeElement);

        const _curClassRef = this;
        $('#issueTable tbody td').unbind();
        $('#issueTable tbody td').on('click', function (event: any) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            // const tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            // const row = table.row(tr);
            if (this.className = 'viewer') {
                _curClassRef.redirect();
            }
        });

        // function view($event: any) {
        //     event.stopPropagation();
        //     this.router.navigate(['/event-viewer']);
        // }
        // $('#viewer').on('click', function() {
        //     event.stopPropagation();
        //     this.router.navigate(['/event-viewer']);
        // });
        // console.log('table is ==>', this.dataTable);
        // $('#view tbody').on('click', 'button', function () {
        //     const data = this.dataTable.row($(this).parents('tr').data);
        //     alert('Data is ==>' + data);
        // });
    }
    redirect() {
        alert('alsjfhksjdf');
    }

    // @HostListener('click')
    // viewer() {
    //     event.stopPropagation();
    //     this.router.navigate(['/event-viewer']);
    // }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        // Called after ngAfterContentInit when the component's view has been initialized. Applies to components only.
        // Add 'implements AfterViewInit' to the class.
        // this.viewer.addEventListener('click', function() {
        //     event.stopPropagation();
        //     // this.router.navigate(['/event-viewer']);
        //     alert('shdfiskludhzj');
        // });
    }
    // viewer() {
    //     alert('sdjfhsklzdjh');
    // }
    // viewer(event: any) {
    //     event.stopPropagation();
    //     this.router.navigate(['/event-viewer']);
    // }
    // buttonInRowClick(event: any): void {
    //     event.stopPropagation();
    //     console.log('Button in the row clicked.');
    //     this.router.navigate(['/event-viewer']);
    // }
    // wholeRowClick(): void {
    //     console.log('Whole row clicked.');
    // }
}
```

But when I click on button, alert doesn't come, how do I fix it?

Comment: You are on ngOnInit so probably Angular didn't have time to render the table when you used JQuery here:


`$('#issueTable tbody td').unbind();` and here `$('#issueTable tbody td').on('click', ...);`
Try wrapping this code in a `setTimeout(()=> { })`

Answer (score 0):

You are on ngOnInit so probably Angular didn't have time to render the table when you used JQuery here:

```
$('#issueTable tbody td').unbind();
$('#issueTable tbody td').on('click', function (event: any) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    // const tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    // const row = table.row(tr);
    if (this.className = 'viewer') {
        _curClassRef.redirect();
    }
});
```

Try wrapping this code in a `setTimeout(()=> { })` like this:

```
setTimeout(()=> { 
    $('#issueTable tbody td').unbind();
    $('#issueTable tbody td').on('click', function (event: any) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        // const tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        // const row = table.row(tr);
        if (this.className = 'viewer') {
            _curClassRef.redirect();
        }
    });
})
```

By doing this you will force the Change Detection to be executed once, which should cause your table to be rendered. Only at that point Jquery will be able to select your HTML elements

Comment: Would you be able to provide a plunkr with a repro of your error?
I can take a further look if i have something to work with :)